# Paint attributes do not work when applied twice

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-paint, staticlayout

I am trying to create a custom impact font with white color and black outline (aka the "meme font").  I have 2 texts on both ends of the canvas but only one of them reflect the changes.  This is so far what I have:

[image]

This is my code:

```
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

        TextPaint topFillPaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomFillPaint = new TextPaint();

        TextPaint topStrokePaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomStrokePaint = new TextPaint();

        Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.impact);

        topFillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topFillPaint.setTextSize(topTextView.getTextSize());
        topFillPaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        topStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        topStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        topStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        topStrokePaint.setTextSize(topTextView.getTextSize());
        topStrokePaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        bottomFillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bottomFillPaint.setTextSize(bottomTextView.getTextSize());
        bottomFillPaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        bottomStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bottomStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        bottomStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bottomStrokePaint.setTextSize(bottomTextView.getTextSize());
        bottomStrokePaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        float topTextMeasurement = topFillPaint.measureText(topText);
        float bottomTextMeasurement = bottomFillPaint.measureText(bottomText);

        StaticLayout topFillLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topFillPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                1.0f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout topStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topStrokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                1.0f, 0.0f, false);


        StaticLayout bottomFillLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomFillPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                1.0f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout bottomStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomStrokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                1.0f, 0.0f, false);

        canvas.translate(0,0);
        topFillLayout.draw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(0,0);
        topStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight() - 210);
        bottomFillLayout.draw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeigth() - 210);
        bottomStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is differences in  coordinates  you are passing to draw bottomStrokeLayout and bottomFillLayout.

```
 canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight() - 210);
 bottomFillLayout.draw(canvas);

canvas.translate(0,canvas.getHeight() -210);
bottomStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?  Sorry.  I don't see it.

Comment: See in your code when you draw Stroke layout for bottom view , there is a diffrence in postion of bottomFillLayout and bottomStrokeLayout.

Comment: I'm putting the same coordinates for both `canvas.translate()` methods.  What difference are you talking about?

Comment: no see your passing width in bottomFillLayout that is written  correct by me in my answer.